# What's the best way to cut out the center piece of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I currently have a square image that i want to use as an input to my ResNet50 with the dimensions 576x576 and am trying to only have the center square of that image. In other words, cut out a border around the center of the image. Is there a way of doing this by only having to define the width of the cut out (in pixels)?

Comment: What's your tools for reading image? what's your order of the image channel?  `C H W` or `H W C` or something else

Comment: I use opencv (e.g. cv2.imread). Channel order is: H W C

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("ImageName.jpg") # or any format you want
area = (400, 400, 800, 800)
cropped_img = img.crop(area)
cropped_img.save("ImageName2.jpg", "JPEG") # or any format you want, even diifferent than the original format.
cropped_img.show()
```

this is a method to crop. define your own algorithim to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example do it something like this:

```
import numpy as np
start_width = 576
center_width = 100

start_image = np.random.rand(start_width,start_width,3)
# With open CV:
# start_image = cv2.imread("your_file",mode='RGB')
# start_width = start_image.shape[0]
center_image_start_idx = int((start_width-center_width)/2)

center_image = start_image[
        center_image_start_idx:(center_image_start_idx+center_width),
        center_image_start_idx:(center_image_start_idx+center_width),:]

print(start_image.shape)
print(center_image.shape)

# Which outputs:
> (576, 576, 3)
> (100, 100, 3)
```

Comment: So I'm reading the image with: `img_array = cv2.imread(img.png)` and using your code like: `center_image[img_array]` and getting the error message: `IndexError: index 184 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100`

Comment: @OmarTekin I wrote the solution before i knew you where having an cv2 image, so I made a general solution. Updated the code such that it should work with cv2 too (see comments in code).
But since you are using cv2 you should probably just use the cv2 supported functions like Mohammad_El_Assal suggested.

Answer (score 0):

suppose `new_h` and `new_w` are your objective height and width.

```
org_h, org_w, _ = img.shape
crop_img = img[org_h//2 - new_h//2:org_h//2 + new_h, org_w//2 - new_w//2:org_w//2 + new_w,:]
```